# How do I change JSF impl of WildFly 27.0.1 from Mojarra 4.0.0.SP01 to MyFaces 4.0

Tags: jsf, wildfly, myfaces, mojarra

Using Red Hat WildFly 27.0.1 I'm trying to migrate Mojarra 4.0.0.SP01 to **MyFaces** 4.0.

Trying to use document "7.26. Jakarta Server Faces Configuration" at:

https://docs.wildfly.org/27/Admin_Guide.html#Jakarta_Server_Faces

Also I can't run "7.26.2. Changing the default Jakarta Server Faces implementation":

```
./jboss-cli.sh /subsystem=jsf/:write-attribute(name=default-jsf-impl-slot,value=<JSF_IMPL_NAME>-<JSF_VERSION>)
```

I find the document conflicts.

Also "Working of the Multi-JSF Implementation" (posted on WildFly Forum).

How can I do this? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

MyFaces works fine with WildFly 27.

MyFaces Wildfly Galleon Pack: https://github.com/melloware/wildfly-myfaces-galleon-pack

And here is an example application using it: https://github.com/melloware/wildfly-faces

Answer (score 0):

Posted on WildFly Forum: "*That support is currently not working correctly. We have an open JIRA to address that, but we've simply had higher priorities. I hope to get to that "soon", but I can't make any promises. Principal Software Engineer, Red Hat JBoss EAP"*

Have upgraded to MyFaces 4.0.0-RC4. Unable to resolve "WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot **'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid**":

```
15:00:15,485 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war")
15:00:17,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for io.aturanj.jakarta.pu
15:00:17,223 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJSF0005: Unknown Jakarta Server Faces version 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0-RC4'.  Default version 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' will be used instead.
15:00:17,223 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war".DEPENDENCIES: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid
    at org.jboss.as.jsf@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFDependencyProcessor.deploy(JSFDependencyProcessor.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more

15:00:17,225 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid"}}
15:00:17,225 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid"}}
15:00:17,226 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid"}}
15:00:17,244 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war (runtime-name: java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war) in 17ms
```

**Next ...**

Have added to WildFly 27 with:

```
com/sun/jsf-impl/myfaces-impl-4.0.0/myfaces-impl-4.0.0-RC4.jar
com/sun/jsf-impl/myfaces-impl-4.0.0/module.xml

javax/faces/api/myfaces-impl-4.0.0/module.xml
javax/faces/api/myfaces-impl-4.0.0/myfaces-api-4.0.0-RC4.jar

org/apache/commons/digester/main/commons-digester3-3.2.jar
org/apache/commons/digester/main/module.xml

org/jboss/as/jsf-injection/myfaces-impl-4.0.0/module.xml
org/jboss/as/jsf-injection/myfaces-impl-4.0.0/weld-jsf-5.1.0.Final.jar
org/jboss/as/jsf-injection/myfaces-impl-4.0.0/weld-jsf-5.1.0.Final.jar
```

Run:

```
./jboss-cli.sh
connect
/subsystem=jsf/:write-attribute(name=default-jsf-impl-slot,value=myfaces-impl-4.0.0)

{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "response-headers" => {
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,
        "process-state" => "reload-required"
    }
}
```

Then:

```
/subsystem=jsf:list-active-jsf-impls()
```

Deployed test WAR:

```
14:03:01,310 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war")
14:03:03,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for io.aturanj.jakarta.pu
14:03:03,455 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJSF0005: Unknown Jakarta Server Faces version 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0'.  Default version 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' will be used instead.
14:03:03,456 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war".DEPENDENCIES: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid
    at org.jboss.as.jsf@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFDependencyProcessor.deploy(JSFDependencyProcessor.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more

14:03:03,458 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid"}}
14:03:03,458 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid"}}
14:03:03,461 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\".DEPENDENCIES" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid"}}
14:03:03,487 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war (runtime-name: java-jakarta-primefaces-1.0.war) in 26ms
14:08:35,964 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) WFLYDR0009: Content /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-preview-27.0.1.Final-MyFaces/standalone/data/content/fc/c21529f2a77775585d0b6dc2bc91c7ae02d4f6 is obsolete and will be removed
14:08:35,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-preview-27.0.1.Final-MyFaces/standalone/data/content/fc/c21529f2a77775585d0b6dc2bc91c7ae02d4f6/content
```

Results still with:

```
Default Jakarta Server Faces implementation slot 'myfaces-impl-4.0.0' is invalid
```

**Answer** - MyFaces won't run/deploy on:

```
wildfly-preview-27.0.1.Final
```

Works with:

```
wildfly-27.0.1.Final
```